# play video and download using webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, download, playback

I need `javascript` code to detect play button of video on web-page in web-view and start downloading on click of button in android web-view

I have used `javascipt` code to solve this issue it download video but didn't play in web-page stuck video play button in website

```
     page.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                            + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                            + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                            + "{"
                            + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                            + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                            + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                            + "console.log(i);"
                            + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                            + "el[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'FBDownloader.processVideo(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"
                            + "}" + "}" + "})()");
                    page.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo;"
                            + ")()");
```

I need `javascript` code that when I click on video default button to play so video starts playing and by clicking on other button defined by me to start download file